# CSS Problem link(a) attribute controlling text color

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I have a problem with my CSS. Here it is:

The CSS for Div main:
`.main {background: #E6E6E6; padding: 2em; heigh:100%;}`
The CSS for links:
`a { color: #8D0D19; }`

The HTML for main:
`<div class="main">
<h3>Welcome</h3><br /> ...More Content Here....
<h3><a href="new.php">New</a></h3>`

The color for the link is burgundy. When a link is present on the page, the whole text on the page becomes burgundy.

I also added color attribute to `.main` but it didn't work. Also I tried making `a`, `.main a` but that also didn't work.

So what should i do to keep my text black and only the links burgundy?

BTW I dont know CSS very well. If you can reccomend me some website, training or book for beginning CSS, that would be great.

Thanks.

Update:
Heres the whole CSS code:

```
* {    margin: 0; }

html { height: 100%; width: 100%; }

body {    height: 100%;    width: 100%;    margin: 0;    padding: 0;    border: 0;    background: #E6E6E6;    font: 13px/15px Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;  }

.wrapper {    min-height: 100%;    height: auto !important;    height: 100%;    margin: 0 auto -42px; }

.header { height: 70px;   text-align: left; background: #1A446C; color: #D4E6F4; }

.header h1 { padding: 1em; margin: 0;} .header a {position: absolute; right:0; top: 0px; text-align: right; padding: 1.25em; margin: 0; color: >#D4E6F4; text-decoration:none;}

.main {color: #000000; background: #E6E6E6; padding: 2em; heigh:100%;} .main a {color: #8D0D19;}

.footer {    height:10px; text-align: center; padding: 7px;    background: #1A446C; color: #D4E6F4;    position:absolute; bottom:0; right:0; left:0; }

img { border: none; }

table, tr, td, tr {    border-collapse: collapse;    vertical-align: top;    text-align: left;    font: 13px/15px Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; }

table.bordered tr th, table.bordered tr td { border: 1px solid #000000; }
```

And Here's the HTML Code:

```
<html>    <head>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />    </head>    <body>
       <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="header">
            <h1>Header</h1><h2><a href="login.php?logout=1">Logout<a/></h2>
                </div>
          <div class="main"><h3>HTML Text Here....</h3><br /><br /> <h3><a href="new.php" >New</a></h3> </div> </div>    <div class="footer">
           <p>Copyright &copy; 2011</p>
       </div>    </body> </html>
```

Update: Test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/hhgGE/

Comment: WORKING FINE HERE : http://jsfiddle.net/xkeshav/ffp5d/1

Comment: u must define some other css on the `a` debug with firebug

Comment: @diEcho he says `'The color for the link is burgundy. When a link is present on the page, the whole text on the page becomes burgundy.'`

Comment: Have you tested in multiple browsers? Is it just the one with the problem?

Comment: @diEcho I know its working fine there, but i tried my whole code, and it gave me the same problem. Let me check the CSS and i'll put  more code.

Comment: @death_au I tested it in Firefox 4 and Chrome 10

Comment: @Arjun Bajaj, it might be worth supplying a live link for us to take a look at.

Comment: i'm developing it on my machine. So i haven't hosted it anywhere. But i added the code above.

Comment: A better idea would be to put it up on jsfiddle.net

Comment: Here's the link: http://jsfiddle.net/hhgGE/

Comment: @Arjun Bajaj, See my updated answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

The bug was caused by a typo in the .header `<a/>` closing tag - should have been `</a>`.

**Here is a live link:** http://jsfiddle.net/RF9cC/1/

***Previous:***

Sounds like the color is being inherited from somewhere else or your not closing the `</a>` tag properly? You could do something like:

```
.main{
color:#000;
}

.main a:link{
color:#8D0D19;
}
```

That should style all the text in the DIV .main as black but any link as the burgundy.

A good (and in-depth) reference to building websites is this e-book by Robert Schifreen:
http://www.the-web-book.com/browse/index.html

It has detailed information on pretty much all there is to know regarding web design.

Comment: hey your code didn't work properly, its giving me the same error. But thanks a lot for the book. Looks like a good book. I'll read it. :D

Comment: See the update to my answer above @Arjun.

Comment: yes... it works... thanks a lot... :D...
its okay if you cant explain... thanks...

Comment: The issue was actually a type in the above a tag as @death_au also pointed out. Definitely fix the type to prevent further glitches.

Answer (score 1):

From what little you've posted, I cant see anything that could be wrong with the css. I'd double check the html to make sure you're properly closing your tags.
**EDIT :** looking at your update, there's a closing `a` tag in there that looks like `<a/>` (line 5, the logout link). it should be `</a>`. This fixes the problem.

As for learning CSS, I can't go past [W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/). Basically tells you everything every CSS element does, what attributes they have, what browsers it works with, etc. And some nice tutorials, too.

Comment: hey, i think i have closed my tags properly, BTW i just posted the whole code. Can you have a look and tell me whats wrong. Thanks. :D

Comment: updated my answer. Looks like your problem was simply a typo. Happens to me all the time :P